# Letter and combination problem

Tags: combinatorics

I am having problem with the question below,

> How many words can be formed out of the letters of the word "courage"?

As the author did not mentioned about repetition so I answer should be 7^7 but the real answer is 7!.
Please help me out why is it so.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's implied that each letter can only be used once. But did the author specify 7-letter words?

Comment: @WilliamD.: No, he did not.

Comment: I would support the claim that there is no clear answer.  If you want 7 letter words  but letters can be duplicated you are right.  If you want 7 letter words without duplicates, 7! is correct.  If you want words without duplication, but shorter than 7 is acceptable you need a sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permutation problem if no letter is to be repeated. So you have $7$ letters and you want to form words with all $7$,  so you should have $\frac{7!}{(7-7)!}=7!$. Alternatively, note that the first position could be filled in $7$ ways since you have $7$ letters, the second position $6$ ways since you have only $6$ letters now and so on. So you have $7!$ words you can form.